# Will `Object.keys(x)` ever throw?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I know for sure if

`Object.keys(x)` will ever throw an error?

where x is anything.

Comment: `Object.keys(null);` or `Object.keys(undefined);`

Comment: Did you try random types?

Comment: Read the documentation!

Comment: You can wrap x inside Object(), eg.: ```Object.keys(Object(x));``` If x is undefined or null or anything it won't throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to add my own answer because people aren't giving you the simplest possible and most complete answer here:

> Will `Object.keys(x)` ever throw?

**Yes it can throw.**  In ES5, it will throw if `x` is not an object.  You can verify this yourself in IE11 or any older browser.

In ES2015, it will throw if `x` is `undefined` or `null`.  Other non-object values such as a number, string or boolean will be coerced into an object and will then return an empty array (since the coerced object has no enumerable properties).

The [ES2015 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.keys) requires that x is coerced into an object (if possible).  This means that it will successfully coerce some things into an object such as a number, boolean, string, but not `null` or `undefined` so even in ES2015, both `Object.keys(null)` and `Object.keys(undefined)` will still throw as tested in Chrome v62.

---

So, if you really wanted to be safe, you would either put a `try/catch` around your code or you would test to see if `x !== null && typeof x === "object"` before calling `Object.keys()`.

```
function safeKeys(val) {
    // test to see if we have a valid non-null object
    if (val && typeof val === "object") {
        return Object.keys(val);
    } else {
        return [];
    }   
}
```

Or, using `try/catch`:

```
function safeKeys(val) {
    try {
        return Object.keys(val);
    } catch(e) {
        return [];
    }
}
```

The `try/catch` is probably ultimately safer in case an imperfect implementation throws in some situation you weren't expecting.

---

> How can I know for sure if `Object.keys(x)` will ever throw an error?

You can read relevant specifications to find out what implementations are ***supposed to do***.  And, you can test pertinent implementations to find out what ***they actually do***.  If you want to really know for sure, you have to test specific implementations.  In an imperfect world, if you want to know something like this that is a little off-the-beaten-path with absolutely certainty, you have to test it yourself and see how they behave.

In this example, a simple test case takes about 2 minutes to code and run in a few relevant environments.  This case was slightly more complicated than usual because the specification and then implementation changed over time (different from ES5 to ES2015).

---

But, **practically speaking**, if you know you might get a non-object there, then it's probably way simpler to just code defensively and in this particular case since you had a moving target of a specification and implementation it's advisable to just code defensively regardless of this aspect of the implementation.  Then, you don't have to know for sure how the underlying platform behaves when given bad data.  Just filter out the bad data up front so it has the behavior you want it to have in that case.

Comment: *"...If you want to really know for sure, you have to test."* Be sure to test all minor point releases of all versions of all browsers on all platforms, for all possible uses. If you can do that in 2 minutes, I'll be impressed. Or just do what most production environments do, and rely on the best available data, and handle it in the extraordinarily rare case of an hitherto unknown implementation bug. Real world.

Comment: @rockstar - The OP asked ***"how do I know for sure?"*** so I'm answering that.  Yes, it is not practical to test all possible features before using them, but if you aren't going to code defensively and therefore your code NEEDs to know, then you have to test to know if you can get away without coding defensively.  For me, if I'm not sure already from prior experience, then I code defensively.  Frankly, it's way faster than testing all relevant environments.  I updated my answer to add info on this.

Comment: Your first `safeKeys` isn't defensive WRT the bugs or future spec changes on which you challenged me. Now you're equivocating. You say you code defensively if you're not already sure from prior experience. Your *prior experience* is an arbitrary metric, and is in essence what I suggested. I have a feeling that you actually operate in the reality that I've described all along, but are pedantic for StackOverflow. No matter. It's just been a pointless debate if you're ending up right were I am.

Comment: @rockstar - Sorry, but I don't know how to code defensively against all possible future spec changes and I wasn't trying to do that.  The first `safeKeys()` is just making sure you're passing in a non-null object which is what `Object.keys()` has always been designed to operate on and designed to do something useful with.  It is attempting to avoid entirely how `Object.keys()` behaves when given a non-object.  That's a very reasonable way to code defensively for this function.  The defense is against how it behaves when given a non-object.

Comment: @rockstar - As for "where you are", your answer offers NO advice for how to actually code a solution here so I have no idea how you're saying I'm arriving at the same point you are.  "Where you are" for coding a solution is simply not defined in your answer.  Nor, would anyone reading our two answers think they are saying anything close to the same thing.

Comment: I think you're not reading what I write. Now you're trying to make it a comparison of answers? My answer tells how to know how JS methods behave. That's what the question is asking. You've challenged me by applying rigid classroom descriptions of things that can go wrong beyond the spec, but when those challenges are thrown back at you, your approach becomes the pragmatic position I've described. So yes, you're right where I was all along. All I had to do was point out how your defensive and testing requirements ultimately fail in the face of real-world unknowns.

Comment: @rockstar - Both of my implementations of `safeKeys()` are using defensive coding techniques.  If you have even better and useful ways to code defensively, then you could demonstrate those and add them to your answer (which you have not done).  You haven't been specific at all about what you think should be done better in mine other than some vague "future spec changes" which if either of these were implemented in 2012 against an ES5 spec would have protected things just fine vs. the ES2015 spec change.  As for future spec changes, who knows.

Comment: @rockstar - I think we're done.  Your answer to "read the spec" is only a small part of the story here.  I thought there was a lot more to a complete and practical answer than to just tell someone to read the spec.  So, I put all that additional info into an answer.  If you think all that is worthless info, that's your opinion.  I think we're done now.

Comment: Why would I add the very defensive techniques that I rejected as ultimately too cumbersome, especially in the face of their ultimate futility? It's fine if you have a different answer, but you're the one who challenged me. I just applied your challenges to your answer. My answer is to read the specs to learn and write code accordingly. If there's a bug out there, then obviously you'd patch it.

Comment: And unless you create "defensive" versions of most or all built-ins, then I'm sure you do just the same. Your "prior experience" is insufficient for the very reasons you threw at me, so you're back to trusting that things work correctly until you learn otherwise.

Comment: @rockstar - Nope, that's not how I write code.  My last paragraph in my answer pretty much says how I would handle this.  If I knew I might get bad data as input, then I'd filter out that bad data before making the function call.  I'd probably do that even before reading a specification and would definitely do it after finding out that there are two versions of the specification with two different behaviors for bad input.

Comment: @rockstar - I don't attempt to know how all built-ins work with bad data.  If I think I have a chance of bad input data and an exception is not a reasonable thing to happen here if there is bad input, then I test for the bad input or catch any potential exception and handle it myself in a 100% predictable way without reading multiple versions of specifications or testing multiple implementations.  Much simpler way to be safe IMO.

Comment: Dealing with bad data where one knows it may be possible is just an every day part of coding in a dynamically typed language. I just don't know what that has to do with knowing under what circumstances `Object.keys` will throw. Without the info in the spec, you'd have nothing to base your type checking on.

Comment: @rockstar - I think I've fully answered the OP's question and am not interested in continuing any further discussion with you.

Comment: I think your answer is fine. It just didn't stand up to your own criticisms of mine. You've since corrected it to better meet your own expectations, but those expectations are still beyond what is being asked. You've been talking yourself in circles trying to avoid that fact. Naturally, you'll not want to continue.

Answer (score 2):

As per documentation [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

> In ES5, if the argument to this method is not an object (a primitive),
>   then it will cause a TypeError. In ES2015, a non-object argument will
>   be coerced to an object.

Comment: And, I verified that with `Object.keys(5)` IE11 will throw and current Chrome v61 will coerce to an object and thus return an empty array.  I don't have ES5 versions of Chrome or Firefox or Safari to try that.